# Filter array in multi label nested array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
class TrackingItem : ObservableObject, Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var trackingNumber: String?
} 

struct ToMeTabResponse : Codable {
    var shipments: [TrackingItem] = []
}       
        
struct ObjectData : Codable {
    var groups: [ToMeTabResponse] = []
}
    
struct BaseViewModel {     
    var objectList: [ObjectData] = []
    var ignoreIds: [String] = ["AB","BC" ]
```

This function `filter` is not returning the expected result. If `trackingNumber` is in the `ignoreIds` then that object should not in `objectList`.

```
func filter
    objectList = objectList.filter { list in
        list.groups.contains(where: {
            $0.shipments.contains(where: { 
                !ignoreIds.contains($0.trackingNumber ?? "")
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want to ignore an entire `ObjectData` instance if any group contains any shipment with an ignored id? Or do you want updated data where only ignored `TrackingItem` instances are removed but the rest of the data is left in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to filter out any `ObjectData` instance that has any group with any shipment with an ignored id then you can use the following:

```
    objectList = objectList.filter { data in
        data.groups.allSatisfy({
            $0.shipments.allSatisfy({
                !ignoreIds.contains($0.trackingNumber ?? "")
            })
        })
    }
```

The use of `allSatisfy` ensures that all entries meet the desired criteria. So if a single `TrackingItem` within all of the shipments of all of the groups of a given `ObjectData` is to be ignored then that entire `ObjectData` will be filtered out of results.

---

If your goal is to create a new copy of the data with just matching `TrackingItem` instances removed (as well as empty shipments and groups) then that is far more complicated. Below is code that will achieve that goal.

`filter(by:)` methods have been added to `and` to make this far more manageable.

The following can be run in a Swift Playground.

```
struct TrackingItem : Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var trackingNumber: String?
}

struct ToMeTabResponse : Codable {
    var shipments: [TrackingItem] = []

    // Create a copy of self while filtering out matching shipments
    func filter(by ids: [String]) -> Self {
        return ToMeTabResponse(shipments: shipments.filter { !ids.contains($0.trackingNumber ?? "") })
    }
}

struct ObjectData : Codable {
    var groups: [ToMeTabResponse] = []

    // Create a copy of self filtering out empty shipments
    func filter(by ids: [String]) -> Self {
        return ObjectData(groups: groups.map { $0.filter(by: ids) }.filter { !$0.shipments.isEmpty })
    }
}

struct BaseViewModel {
    var objectList: [ObjectData] = []
    var ignoreIds: [String] = ["AB","BC" ]

    // Update objectList by filtering out matching TrackingItems and removing ObjectData instances with empty groups
    mutating func filter() {
        objectList = objectList.map { $0.filter(by: ignoreIds) }.filter { !$0.groups.isEmpty }
    }
}

var x = BaseViewModel()
x.objectList = [
    ObjectData(groups: [
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "AB"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "XY"),
        ]),
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "GF"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "HY"),
        ]),
    ]),
    ObjectData(groups: [
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "QW"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "NN"),
        ]),
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "TT"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "OO"),
        ]),
    ]),
    ObjectData(groups: [
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "HG"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "JU"),
        ]),
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "AB"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "BC"),
        ]),
    ]),
    ObjectData(groups: [
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "BC"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "AB"),
        ]),
        ToMeTabResponse(shipments: [
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "AB"),
            TrackingItem(trackingNumber: "BC"),
        ]),
    ]),
]

x.filter()
print(x.objectList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I exactly want.  see in `ToMeTabResponse` there is multiple shipments so I want remove only that shipment not complete `ToMeTabResponse` object.

Comment: @HarendraTiwari I've updated my answer with an alternate solution that I think matches your requirement. If you want to leave empty shipments and groups then it is an easy change to remove calls to `filter` that check `isEmpty`.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this solution.